# VideoJS Custom display time duration and current time overlaps

Tags: css, html, video.js, video-player

I was to display total time duration and current time of video in the skin by modifying related css settings as shown in the picture:
[image]

But I am currently facing an issue of time display overlapping when total time is more than an hour.

See this: 
[image]

current time and total time of video overlaps for long duration videos.

Can anyone help me to counter this problem?
Can it be done with CSS only or I'll have to use JavaScript to change witdh etc. according to time.

CSS for displaying Video Time Duration:

```
.vjs-sublime-skin .vjs-current-time{
display: block;
margin-top: 5px;
position: absolute;
right: 155px;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
}
.vjs-sublime-skin .vjs-time-divider{
display: block;
margin-top: 5px;
position: absolute;
right: 148px;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
}
.vjs-sublime-skin .vjs-duration{
display: block;
margin-top: 5px;
position: absolute;
right: 125px;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
}
```

Regards,

Comment: Can you also supply the HTML of the player? With that it could be easier to answer.